# Trouble with deploying ear-file in Payara 5, that contains ejb-module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, payara

I'm trying to deploy ear file, that contains ejb module in dependecies in Payara 5.184 and getting error:

```
11.02.2019 13:57:15.938 | [payara-executor-service-scheduled-task] | ERROR | Exception while deploying the app [my-ear-SNAPSHOT]
11.02.2019 13:57:15.945 | [payara-executor-service-scheduled-task] | ERROR | Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ejb jar [lib/my-ejb.jar]: it contains zero ejb. 
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style),
   or message-driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component
   level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton),
   please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.
```

With payara 4.1, this error does not occur. What should I do to fix the deployment error?

There is short version of my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-ears</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib/</defaultJavaBundleDir>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>my</groupId>
                            <artifactId>my-ejb</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>/lib</bundleDir>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It seems that the ejb-jar contains zero EJBs! Are you sure that the conditions (1) & (2) in the error message note are met? If so, try checking the logs for note (3).

Comment: Class in this ejb module is annotated by @Stateless. Before the error in log:
WARN  | Unable to construct HTTP/2 Addon
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.grizzly.npn.AlpnServerNegotiator

ERROR | Exception while parsing file file:/%path to domain%/applications/my-ear-1.4.3.1.1-SNAPSHOT/
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@348af191 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@473122d5[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 20, queued tasks = 25, completed tasks = 19]

Comment: After run asadmin set-payara-executor-service-configuration --threadpoolexecutorqueuesize 1000 --port 8556 the error has changed.
Exception during lifecycle processing javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PaymentsGroupJob not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in domain.xml. I just copy it from payara 4.1 config folder and it was the wrong decision. The correct approach is this: take the original file and consistently make changes to it. Unfortunately, there is one more problem with EJB, but all the errors described above are gone.